# activeMq redeliveryPolicy ignored when passed from tomee to spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jms, activemq-classic, apache-tomee

i have a simple spring app deployed in tomee 1.7.1 with activeMq 5.10.
my issue is that the redelivery policy i set seems to be ignored mainly the delay on redelivery.

Im my jms listener i immediately throw an exception to test the automatic retries.

my activemq.xml is this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
    http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd
">
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" />
<!-- 
    The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker. 
-->
<amq:broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" useShutdownHook="false" enableStatistics="true" brokerName="bima" useJmx="true" tmpDataDirectory="${catalina.base}/activemq-data/localhost/tmp_storage" populateJMSXUserID="true" useAuthenticatedPrincipalForJMSXUserID="true" schedulerSupport="true">

    <amq:connectionFactory id="jmsRedeliverConnectionFactory" brokerURL="vm://localhost">
      <amq:redeliveryPolicy>
        <amq:redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="5" initialRedeliveryDelay="1000" redeliveryUseExponentialBackOff ="true" backOffMultiplier="5" />
      </amq:redeliveryPolicy>

    <amq:persistenceAdapter>
        <amq:kahaDB directory="${catalina.base}/activemq-data/kahadb" checkForCorruptJournalFiles="true" checksumJournalFiles="true" journalMaxFileLength="32mb"/>
    </amq:persistenceAdapter>

    <managementContext>
       <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
    </managementContext>
</amq:broker>
```

And my tomee.xml looks like this:

```
<tomee>
    <Resource id="ActiveMQResourceAdapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
        BrokerXmlConfig=broker:(vm://localhost)
        <!-- ServerUrl=vm://localhost -->
    </Resource>

  <!-- see http://tomee.apache.org/containers-and-resources.html -->
  <Resource id="resources/jms/ConnectionFactory" type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"> 
       ResourceAdapter = ActiveMQResourceAdapter 
       BrokerURL = vm://localhost
       maximumRedeliveries 3
       redeliveryBackOffMultiplier 2
       redeliveryUseExponentialBackOff true
       initialRedeliveryDelay 5000
       <!-- BrokerUrl = tcp://localhost:61616 -->
    </Resource> 

    <Resource id="resources/jms/XAConnectionFactory" class-name="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory">
        BrokerURL = vm://localhost

    </Resource>

    <Resource id="resources/jms/PrintQueue" type="javax.jms.Queue"/>


    <Resource id="testxa" class-name="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource">
        Url jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true
        User root
    </Resource>

    <Resource id="movieDatabase" type="DataSource">
        XaDataSource testxa
        DataSourceCreator dbcp
        UserName root
    </Resource>

  <!-- activate next line to be able to deploy applications in apps -->
    <Deployments dir="apps" />
</tomee>
```

and my jms beans in my aplication context looks like this:

```
<bean id="StartQueue" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <ref local="jmsFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="defaultDestinationName" value="StartQueue" />
    <property name="deliveryPersistent" value="true"/>
    <property name="explicitQosEnabled" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="starter" class="org.superbiz.mdb.Start"/>
<jms:listener-container container-type="default" connection-factory="jmsFactory" cache="none" acknowledge="auto" transaction-manager="transactionManager"  concurrency="1" >
    <jms:listener destination="StartQueue" ref="starter" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

once i added the maximumRedeliveries 3 to the tomee xml that started to work but the redeliveries all happen with no delay. So something is ignoring the useExponentialBackOff and the initialRedeliveryDelay or am i missing setting it somewhere?

EDIT:

So i configured tomee to use an external broker activemq 5.10.0 with the broker config

```
    <!-- START SNIPPET: example -->
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="logQuery" class="org.fusesource.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>

    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" schedulerSupport="true">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>

        <plugins>
                    <redeliveryPlugin fallbackToDeadLetter="true" sendToDlqIfMaxRetriesExceeded="true">
                        <redeliveryPolicyMap>
                            <redeliveryPolicyMap>
                                <defaultEntry>
                                    <redeliveryPolicy  maximumRedeliveries="5" initialRedeliveryDelay="1000" redeliveryDelay="1000" useExponentialBackOff ="true"  backOffMultiplier="5"/>
                                </defaultEntry>
                            </redeliveryPolicyMap>
                        </redeliveryPolicyMap>
                    </redeliveryPlugin>
                </plugins>
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb" checkForCorruptJournalFiles="true" checksumJournalFiles="true" journalMaxFileLength="32mb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>

          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61617?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
<!-- END SNIPPET: example -->
```

and the tomee xml

```
    <tomee>

    <Resource id="ActiveMQResourceAdapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
        # Do not start the embedded ActiveMQ broker
        BrokerXmlConfig  =
        ServerUrl = tcp://10.81.1.28:61617>
    </Resource>

    <Resource id="resources/jms/ConnectionFactory" type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"> 
        ResourceAdapter = ActiveMQResourceAdapter 
       maximumRedeliveries 1
    </Resource> 
    <Resource id="testxa" class-name="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource">
        Url jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true
        User root
    </Resource>

    <Resource id="movieDatabase" type="DataSource">
        XaDataSource testxa
        DataSourceCreator dbcp
        UserName root
    </Resource>

  <!-- activate next line to be able to deploy applications in apps -->
    <Deployments dir="apps" />
</tomee>
```

This works and the queue gets redelivered expediently when i try and have tomee start the activemq with the same activemq xml and the tomee xml of

```
    <tomee>
    <Resource id="ActiveMQResourceAdapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
        BrokerXmlConfig=broker:(vm://localhost)
        BrokerURL = vm://localhost
    </Resource>

  <Resource id="resources/jms/ConnectionFactory" type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">
       ResourceAdapter = ActiveMQResourceAdapter
       maximumRedeliveries 1
    </Resource>


    <Resource id="testxa" class-name="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource">
        Url jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true
        User root
    </Resource>

    <Resource id="movieDatabase" type="DataSource">
        XaDataSource testxa
        DataSourceCreator dbcp
        UserName root
    </Resource>

  <!-- activate next line to be able to deploy applications in apps -->
    <Deployments dir="apps" />
</tomee>
```

the configurations are ignored and the queue is not redelivered something else needed to be done so tomee uses the redelivery policy?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is redeliveryUseExponentialBackOff and not useExponentialBackOff: http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.10.0/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ra/ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory.html

Basically use setters.

Comment: That does not work either but i agree thats what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Why not setting it on resource adapter BTW?

Comment: i moved it their while tying to get it to accept any setting i pass in if i set it their i get 7 retries and no delay if i move it to the connection factory i at least get the correct number of retries

Answer (score 0):

By default tomee deactivate scheduler service so maybe this doesnt work with the embedded broker.

Did you try using an external one of adding jar needed to support xbean xml configuration of the broker? (http://tomee.apache.org/jms-resources-and-mdb-container.html)

Comment: i modified it to use a external broker and get the same exact results

Comment: Ok, so turns out I had something incorrectly configured. I now have the external broker running and my app is publishing to it, but my message listener is still listening to the embedded broker. Is there a configuration that I'm missing that allows my MDB to connect to the external broker beyond setting up the connection factory in the tomee.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Answering this old question so maybe someone might benefit from this (I came across a lot of similar questions). I've had a similar problem where the RedeliveryPolicy was not applied correctly. By setting the maximumRedeliveries to -1 it was infinitely retrying to process the message, but the delays were ignored. Turned out that redelivery was not working correcty due to the default `cacheLevel` field on Springs DefaultMessageListenerContainer.

Setting this level to `CACHE_CONSUMER` solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

To help with this old question. Tomee with connection factory obtained from the resource adapter performs server side redelivery. On the other hand spring default message listener container performs redelivery on the client.

After trial and error the only way for redelivery to work with spring jms and tomee is to use jca message endpoints described here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/jms/jca-message-endpoint-manager.html you can lookup jca connector using jndi. You can then define redelivery on adapter in tomee or per destination using activation specs.